# Bootstrap Responsive Margins & Padding Less/CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less

I've created a series of CSS classes to easily manipulate the margins and padding of various elements. I've also utilized media queries to create responsive classes that only apply at certain screen widths. Everything appears to work as it should, but as you can see, my Less writing skills are extremely lacking and the code is huge!

I know far less code could be used to output the required CSS, but all of my attempts to write the custom mixin's and loops have come up short.

Is it possible to reduce this block of code to something a little slicker? Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

```
// Margins and padding
// -------------------------

// Horizontal and vertical offset values
@x-0:       0;
@x-xs:      (@grid-gutter-width / 4);
@x-sm:      (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
@x-md:      @grid-gutter-width;
@x-lg:      (@grid-gutter-width * 2);
@x-xl:      (@grid-gutter-width * 4);

@y-0:       0;
@y-xs:      (@line-height-computed / 4);
@y-sm:      (@line-height-computed / 2);
@y-md:      @line-height-computed;
@y-lg:      (@line-height-computed * 2);
@y-xl:      (@line-height-computed * 4);

// Static margins
.mt-0  { margin-top: @y-0; }
.mt-xs { margin-top: @y-xs; }
.mt-sm { margin-top: @y-sm; }
.mt-md { margin-top: @y-md; }
.mt-lg { margin-top: @y-lg; }
.mt-xl { margin-top: @y-xl; }

.mr-0  { margin-right: @x-0; }
.mr-xs { margin-right: @x-xs; }
.mr-sm { margin-right: @x-sm; }
.mr-md { margin-right: @x-md; }
.mr-lg { margin-right: @x-lg; }
.mr-xl { margin-right: @x-xl; }

.mb-0  { margin-bottom: @y-0; }
.mb-xs { margin-bottom: @y-xs; }
.mb-sm { margin-bottom: @y-sm; }
.mb-md { margin-bottom: @y-md; }
.mb-lg { margin-bottom: @y-lg; }
.mb-xl { margin-bottom: @y-xl; }

.ml-0  { margin-left: @x-0; }
.ml-xs { margin-left: @x-xs; }
.ml-sm { margin-left: @x-sm; }
.ml-md { margin-left: @x-md; }
.ml-lg { margin-left: @x-lg; }
.ml-xl { margin-left: @x-xl; }

// Responsive margins
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    .mt-0-sm  { margin-top: @y-0; }
    .mt-xs-sm { margin-top: @y-xs; }
    .mt-sm-sm { margin-top: @y-sm; }
    .mt-md-sm { margin-top: @y-md; }
    .mt-lg-sm { margin-top: @y-lg; }
    .mt-xl-sm { margin-top: @y-xl; }

    .mr-0-sm  { margin-right: @x-0; }
    .mr-xs-sm { margin-right: @x-xs; }
    .mr-sm-sm { margin-right: @x-sm; }
    .mr-md-sm { margin-right: @x-md; }
    .mr-lg-sm { margin-right: @x-lg; }
    .mr-xl-sm { margin-right: @x-xl; }

    .mb-0-sm  { margin-bottom: @y-0; }
    .mb-xs-sm { margin-bottom: @y-xs; }
    .mb-sm-sm { margin-bottom: @y-sm; }
    .mb-md-sm { margin-bottom: @y-md; }
    .mb-lg-sm { margin-bottom: @y-lg; }
    .mb-xl-sm { margin-bottom: @y-xl; }

    .ml-0-sm  { margin-left: @x-0; }
    .ml-xs-sm { margin-left: @x-xs; }
    .ml-sm-sm { margin-left: @x-sm; }
    .ml-md-sm { margin-left: @x-md; }
    .ml-lg-sm { margin-left: @x-lg; }
    .ml-xl-sm { margin-left: @x-xl; }
}
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    .mt-0-md  { margin-top: @y-0; }
    .mt-xs-md { margin-top: @y-xs; }
    .mt-sm-md { margin-top: @y-sm; }
    .mt-md-md { margin-top: @y-md; }
    .mt-lg-md { margin-top: @y-lg; }
    .mt-xl-md { margin-top: @y-xl; }

    .mr-0-md  { margin-right: @x-0; }
    .mr-xs-md { margin-right: @x-xs; }
    .mr-sm-md { margin-right: @x-sm; }
    .mr-md-md { margin-right: @x-md; }
    .mr-lg-md { margin-right: @x-lg; }
    .mr-xl-md { margin-right: @x-xl; }

    .mb-0-md  { margin-bottom: @y-0; }
    .mb-xs-md { margin-bottom: @y-xs; }
    .mb-sm-md { margin-bottom: @y-sm; }
    .mb-md-md { margin-bottom: @y-md; }
    .mb-lg-md { margin-bottom: @y-lg; }
    .mb-xl-md { margin-bottom: @y-xl; }

    .ml-0-md  { margin-left: @x-0; }
    .ml-xs-md { margin-left: @x-xs; }
    .ml-sm-md { margin-left: @x-sm; }
    .ml-md-md { margin-left: @x-md; }
    .ml-lg-md { margin-left: @x-lg; }
    .ml-xl-md { margin-left: @x-xl; }
}
@media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
    .mt-0-lg  { margin-top: @y-0; }
    .mt-xs-lg { margin-top: @y-xs; }
    .mt-sm-lg { margin-top: @y-sm; }
    .mt-md-lg { margin-top: @y-md; }
    .mt-lg-lg { margin-top: @y-lg; }
    .mt-xl-lg { margin-top: @y-xl; }

    .mr-0-lg  { margin-right: @x-0; }
    .mr-xs-lg { margin-right: @x-xs; }
    .mr-sm-lg { margin-right: @x-sm; }
    .mr-md-lg { margin-right: @x-md; }
    .mr-lg-lg { margin-right: @x-lg; }
    .mr-xl-lg { margin-right: @x-xl; }

    .mb-0-lg  { margin-bottom: @y-0; }
    .mb-xs-lg { margin-bottom: @y-xs; }
    .mb-sm-lg { margin-bottom: @y-sm; }
    .mb-md-lg { margin-bottom: @y-md; }
    .mb-lg-lg { margin-bottom: @y-lg; }
    .mb-xl-lg { margin-bottom: @y-xl; }

    .ml-0-lg  { margin-left: @x-0; }
    .ml-xs-lg { margin-left: @x-xs; }
    .ml-sm-lg { margin-left: @x-sm; }
    .ml-md-lg { margin-left: @x-md; }
    .ml-lg-lg { margin-left: @x-lg; }
    .ml-xl-lg { margin-left: @x-xl; }
}

// Static padding
.pt-0  { padding-top: @y-0; }
.pt-xs { padding-top: @y-xs; }
.pt-sm { padding-top: @y-sm; }
.pt-md { padding-top: @y-md; }
.pt-lg { padding-top: @y-lg; }
.pt-xl { padding-top: @y-xl; }

.pr-0  { padding-right: @x-0; }
.pr-xs { padding-right: @x-xs; }
.pr-sm { padding-right: @x-sm; }
.pr-md { padding-right: @x-md; }
.pr-lg { padding-right: @x-lg; }
.pr-xl { padding-right: @x-xl; }

.pb-0  { padding-bottom: @y-0; }
.pb-xs { padding-bottom: @y-xs; }
.pb-sm { padding-bottom: @y-sm; }
.pb-md { padding-bottom: @y-md; }
.pb-lg { padding-bottom: @y-lg; }
.pb-xl { padding-bottom: @y-xl; }

.pl-0  { padding-left: @x-0; }
.pl-xs { padding-left: @x-xs; }
.pl-sm { padding-left: @x-sm; }
.pl-md { padding-left: @x-md; }
.pl-lg { padding-left: @x-lg; }
.pl-xl { padding-left: @x-xl; }

// Responsive padding
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    .pt-0-sm  { padding-top: @y-0; }
    .pt-xs-sm { padding-top: @y-xs; }
    .pt-sm-sm { padding-top: @y-sm; }
    .pt-md-sm { padding-top: @y-md; }
    .pt-lg-sm { padding-top: @y-lg; }
    .pt-xl-sm { padding-top: @y-xl; }

    .pr-0-sm  { padding-right: @x-0; }
    .pr-xs-sm { padding-right: @x-xs; }
    .pr-sm-sm { padding-right: @x-sm; }
    .pr-md-sm { padding-right: @x-md; }
    .pr-lg-sm { padding-right: @x-lg; }
    .pr-xl-sm { padding-right: @x-xl; }

    .pb-0-sm  { padding-bottom: @y-0; }
    .pb-xs-sm { padding-bottom: @y-xs; }
    .pb-sm-sm { padding-bottom: @y-sm; }
    .pb-md-sm { padding-bottom: @y-md; }
    .pb-lg-sm { padding-bottom: @y-lg; }
    .pb-xl-sm { padding-bottom: @y-xl; }

    .pl-0-sm  { padding-left: @x-0; }
    .pl-xs-sm { padding-left: @x-xs; }
    .pl-sm-sm { padding-left: @x-sm; }
    .pl-md-sm { padding-left: @x-md; }
    .pl-lg-sm { padding-left: @x-lg; }
    .pl-xl-sm { padding-left: @x-xl; }
}
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    .pt-0-md  { padding-top: @y-0; }
    .pt-xs-md { padding-top: @y-xs; }
    .pt-sm-md { padding-top: @y-sm; }
    .pt-md-md { padding-top: @y-md; }
    .pt-lg-md { padding-top: @y-lg; }
    .pt-xl-md { padding-top: @y-xl; }

    .pr-0-md  { padding-right: @x-0; }
    .pr-xs-md { padding-right: @x-xs; }
    .pr-sm-md { padding-right: @x-sm; }
    .pr-md-md { padding-right: @x-md; }
    .pr-lg-md { padding-right: @x-lg; }
    .pr-xl-md { padding-right: @x-xl; }

    .pb-0-md  { padding-bottom: @y-0; }
    .pb-xs-md { padding-bottom: @y-xs; }
    .pb-sm-md { padding-bottom: @y-sm; }
    .pb-md-md { padding-bottom: @y-md; }
    .pb-lg-md { padding-bottom: @y-lg; }
    .pb-xl-md { padding-bottom: @y-xl; }

    .pl-0-md  { padding-left: @x-0; }
    .pl-xs-md { padding-left: @x-xs; }
    .pl-sm-md { padding-left: @x-sm; }
    .pl-md-md { padding-left: @x-md; }
    .pl-lg-md { padding-left: @x-lg; }
    .pl-xl-md { padding-left: @x-xl; }
}
@media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
    .pt-0-lg  { padding-top: @y-0; }
    .pt-xs-lg { padding-top: @y-xs; }
    .pt-sm-lg { padding-top: @y-sm; }
    .pt-md-lg { padding-top: @y-md; }
    .pt-lg-lg { padding-top: @y-lg; }
    .pt-xl-lg { padding-top: @y-xl; }

    .pr-0-lg  { padding-right: @x-0; }
    .pr-xs-lg { padding-right: @x-xs; }
    .pr-sm-lg { padding-right: @x-sm; }
    .pr-md-lg { padding-right: @x-md; }
    .pr-lg-lg { padding-right: @x-lg; }
    .pr-xl-lg { padding-right: @x-xl; }

    .pb-0-lg  { padding-bottom: @y-0; }
    .pb-xs-lg { padding-bottom: @y-xs; }
    .pb-sm-lg { padding-bottom: @y-sm; }
    .pb-md-lg { padding-bottom: @y-md; }
    .pb-lg-lg { padding-bottom: @y-lg; }
    .pb-xl-lg { padding-bottom: @y-xl; }

    .pl-0-lg  { padding-left: @x-0; }
    .pl-xs-lg { padding-left: @x-xs; }
    .pl-sm-lg { padding-left: @x-sm; }
    .pl-md-lg { padding-left: @x-md; }
    .pl-lg-lg { padding-left: @x-lg; }
    .pl-xl-lg { padding-left: @x-xl; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible (not counting that such hardcoding of every-single value for every single property as a CSS class is considered as very bad practice). Either way, we won't write your code for you. No matter how lacking your Less writing skills are, start with a basic loop and ask for particular problems/difficulties you face.

Comment: I’m developing a very complex dashboard that requires precise positioning and spacing, which is the reason I’ve created all of these classes. I’m dealing with dozens and dozens of elements on a single page, and applying unique margins and padding through existing classes would be impractical and/or impossible at times. I’ve determined that this is the most practical way to manipulate the positioning & spacing of a single element that shares its current class(es) with many other similar elements.

Could you suggest another way to achieve the same level of targeting and positioning precision?

Comment: "Could you suggest another way to achieve the same level of targeting and positioning precision?" - sorry, but this is to wide question to discuss in SO comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Bass Jobsen for doing the majority of the legwork here! For those of you who may be interested, here is the final version I'm using now:

```
@grid-gutter-width: 16px;
@line-height-computed: 16px;

@screen-xs-max: 767px;
@screen-sm-max: 991px;
@screen-md-max: 1199px;

// Horizontal and vertical offsets
@x-0:       0;
@x-xs:      (@grid-gutter-width / 4);    // 4px
@x-sm:      (@grid-gutter-width / 2);    // 8px
@x-md:      @grid-gutter-width;          // 16px
@x-lg:      (@grid-gutter-width * 2);    // 32px
@x-xl:      (@grid-gutter-width * 4);    // 64px

@y-0:       0;
@y-xs:      (@line-height-computed / 4); // 4px
@y-sm:      (@line-height-computed / 2); // 8px
@y-md:      @line-height-computed;       // 16px
@y-lg:      (@line-height-computed * 2); // 32px
@y-xl:      (@line-height-computed * 4); // 64px

@positions: t top, r right, b bottom, l left;
@sizes: 0, xs, sm, md, lg, xl;

.axis(@i) when (mod(@i, 2) = 0) {
    @axis: x;
}
.axis(@i) when (default()) {
    @axis: y;
}

.prop(@property) when (@property = margin) {
    @prop: m;
}
.prop(@property) when (@property = padding) {
    @prop: p;
}

.rules(@prop, @pos, @sizes, @axis, @postfix, @property, @position, @i: 1) when (@i <= length(@sizes)) {

    @size: extract(@sizes, @i);
    @offset: ~"@{axis}-@{size}";

    .@{prop}@{pos}-@{size}@{postfix} {
        @{property}-@{position}: @@offset;
    }

    .rules(@prop, @pos, @sizes, @axis, @postfix, @property, @position, (@i + 1));
}

.ruleset(@positions, @property, @postfix: ~"", @i: 1) when (@i <= length(@positions)) {

    @pos: extract(extract(@positions, @i), 1); 
    @position: extract(extract(@positions, @i), 2);

    .axis(@i);
    .prop(@property);

    .rules(@prop, @pos, @sizes, @axis, @postfix, @property, @position);

    .ruleset(@positions, @property, @postfix, (@i + 1));
}

// Margin & padding modifiers
.ruleset(@positions, margin);
.ruleset(@positions, padding);

// Responsive margin & padding modifiers
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    .ruleset(@positions, margin, -sm);
    .ruleset(@positions, padding, -sm);
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    .ruleset(@positions, margin, -md);
    .ruleset(@positions, padding, -md);
}

@media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
    .ruleset(@positions, margin, -lg);
    .ruleset(@positions, padding, -lg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
@grid-gutter-width: 20px;
@line-height-computed: 40px;

// Margins and padding
// -------------------------

// Horizontal and vertical offset values
@x-0:       0;
@x-xs:      (@grid-gutter-width / 4);
@x-sm:      (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
@x-md:      @grid-gutter-width;
@x-lg:      (@grid-gutter-width * 2);
@x-xl:      (@grid-gutter-width * 4);

@y-0:       0;
@y-xs:      (@line-height-computed / 4);
@y-sm:      (@line-height-computed / 2);
@y-md:      @line-height-computed;
@y-lg:      (@line-height-computed * 2);
@y-xl:      (@line-height-computed * 4);

@positions: t top, r right, b bottom, l left;
@grids: 0, xs, md, lg, xl;

.what(@i) when (mod(@i, 2) = 0) {
  @what: x;
}
.what(@i) when (default()) {
  @what: y;
}

.properties(@prefix, @postfix, @whitespace, @what, @position, @grids, @i: 1) when (@i <= length(@grids)) {

  @grid: extract(@grids,@i);

  .m@{prefix}-@{grid}@{postfix} {
    @var: ~"@{what}-@{grid}";
    @{whitespace}-@{position}: @@var;

  }

  .properties(@prefix, @postfix, @whitespace, @what, @position, @grids, (@i + 1));
}

.whitespace(@positions, @whitespace: margin, @postfix: ~"", @i: 1) when (@i <= length(@positions)) {

  @class: extract(extract(@positions, @i), 1); 
  @position: extract(extract(@positions, @i), 2);

  .what(@i);
  .properties(@class, @postfix, @whitespace, @what, @position, @grids);

  .whitespace(@positions, @whitespace, @postfix, (@i + 1));
}

.whitespace(@positions);
.whitespace(@positions, padding);

@screen-xs-max: 767px;
@screen-sm-max: 767px;

// Responsive
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
.whitespace(@positions, margin, -sm);
.whitespace(@positions, padding, -sm);
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
.whitespace(@positions, margin, -md);
.whitespace(@positions, padding, -md);
}
```

The above compiles into the CSS code like that shown beneath:

```
.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.mt-xs {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.mt-md {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.mt-lg {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.mt-xl {
  margin-top: 160px;
}
.mr-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.mr-xs {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.mr-md {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.mr-lg {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.mr-xl {
  margin-right: 80px;
}
.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.mb-xs {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.mb-md {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.mb-lg {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.mb-xl {
  margin-bottom: 160px;
}
.ml-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.ml-xs {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.ml-md {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.ml-lg {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.ml-xl {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
.mt-0 {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.mt-xs {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.mt-md {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.mt-lg {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.mt-xl {
  padding-top: 160px;
}
.mr-0 {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.mr-xs {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.mr-md {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.mr-lg {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.mr-xl {
  padding-right: 80px;
}
.mb-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.mb-xs {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.mb-md {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.mb-lg {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.mb-xl {
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}
.ml-0 {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.ml-xs {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.ml-md {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.ml-lg {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.ml-xl {
  padding-left: 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mt-0-sm {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .mt-xs-sm {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .mt-md-sm {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .mt-lg-sm {
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .mt-xl-sm {
    margin-top: 160px;
  }
  .mr-0-sm {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .mr-xs-sm {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .mr-md-sm {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .mr-lg-sm {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  .mr-xl-sm {
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .mb-0-sm {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mb-xs-sm {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .mb-md-sm {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .mb-lg-sm {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
  }
  .mb-xl-sm {
    margin-bottom: 160px;
  }
  .ml-0-sm {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .ml-xs-sm {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .ml-md-sm {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .ml-lg-sm {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
  .ml-xl-sm {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
  .mt-0-sm {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .mt-xs-sm {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .mt-md-sm {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .mt-lg-sm {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .mt-xl-sm {
    padding-top: 160px;
  }
  .mr-0-sm {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .mr-xs-sm {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  .mr-md-sm {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .mr-lg-sm {
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
  .mr-xl-sm {
    padding-right: 80px;
  }
  .mb-0-sm {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mb-xs-sm {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .mb-md-sm {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .mb-lg-sm {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
  }
  .mb-xl-sm {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
  }
  .ml-0-sm {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .ml-xs-sm {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .ml-md-sm {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .ml-lg-sm {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  .ml-xl-sm {
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mt-0-md {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .mt-xs-md {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .mt-md-md {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .mt-lg-md {
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .mt-xl-md {
    margin-top: 160px;
  }
  .mr-0-md {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .mr-xs-md {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .mr-md-md {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .mr-lg-md {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  .mr-xl-md {
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .mb-0-md {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mb-xs-md {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .mb-md-md {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .mb-lg-md {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
  }
  .mb-xl-md {
    margin-bottom: 160px;
  }
  .ml-0-md {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .ml-xs-md {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .ml-md-md {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .ml-lg-md {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
  .ml-xl-md {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
  .mt-0-md {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .mt-xs-md {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .mt-md-md {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .mt-lg-md {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .mt-xl-md {
    padding-top: 160px;
  }
  .mr-0-md {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .mr-xs-md {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  .mr-md-md {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .mr-lg-md {
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
  .mr-xl-md {
    padding-right: 80px;
  }
  .mb-0-md {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mb-xs-md {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .mb-md-md {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .mb-lg-md {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
  }
  .mb-xl-md {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
  }
  .ml-0-md {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .ml-xs-md {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .ml-md-md {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .ml-lg-md {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  .ml-xl-md {
    padding-left: 80px;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Bass! I had no idea the functional Less I required would end up being so complex. I guess that's why all of my attempts failed... I tried to simplify things too much. I did notice one error however: The compiled CSS renders the margin classes twice (every class being prefixed with an 'm'), while the padding classes are excluded (they should be prefixed with a 'p'). Not to worry, I should be able to take it from here. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm also experiencing an unusual parse error at the = symbol in the .properties function. The Less looks fine to me. Might you be able to offer any explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: how do you compile the Less code into CSS code? See also http://codepen.io/bassjobsen/pen/waNxXJ, i think it should work

Comment: You're correct. It should work. I compile using the command-line and I just realized I'm running v1.3, which is far from the latest stable release of v2.5. Hopefully, updating my version of Less will correct the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is available in Bootstrap 4 now.